# Android inflate view multiple time with custom View

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I created a custom class to quickly create View object (basically it's just a question displayed). Exemple :

> Title : Weather
>
> Message : How is the weather today?

So here is my custom class extending View :

```
public class Question extends View {

    Context mContext;

    public Question(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void addQuestion (View rootView, String title, String message) {

        // Inflate une question
        LinearLayout rootQuestion = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activity_formulaire_questions_preliminaires_ll_wrapper);
        LayoutInflater questionInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout myQuestion = (LinearLayout) questionInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_formulaire_question, rootQuestion);

        // Assigne la vue au controlleur
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) myQuestion.findViewById(R.id.activity_formulaire_question_title);
        TextView tvMessage = (TextView) myQuestion.findViewById(R.id.activity_formulaire_question_message);

        // Remplissage des champs textes
        tvTitle.setText(title);
        tvMessage.setText(message);
    }
```

And my fragment :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_formulaire_questions_preliminaires, null);

        Question question = new Question(super.getActivity());
        question.addQuestion(rootView, "Question 1 Title", "1");
        question.addQuestion(rootView, "Question 2 Title", "2");
        question.addQuestion(rootView, "Question 3 Title", "3");
        question.addQuestion(rootView, "Question 4 Title", "4");

        return rootView;
    }
```

BUT when launching the fragment, it is only the last question correctly displayed.

-> Question 4 Title

### -> 4

-> Default title

### -> -1

-> Default title

### -> -1

-> Default title

### -> -1

**Why ?** I though when using questionInflater.inflate I would get a new View, and respecting the hierarchy "View -> ViewGroup -> LinearLayout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this in many ways. 
For example you don't need actually to extend View in this case.

Something like this should work:

```
 public class QuestionHelper {
     Context mContext;

     public QuestionHelper(Context context) {
         mContext = context;
     }

     public void addQuestion(ViewGroup rootView, String title, String message) {
         // Inflate une question
         LayoutInflater questionInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         LinearLayout myQuestion = (LinearLayout) questionInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_formulaire_question, null, false);

         // Assigne la vue au controlleur
         TextView tvTitle = (TextView) myQuestion.findViewById(R.id.activity_formulaire_question_title);
         TextView tvMessage = (TextView) myQuestion.findViewById(R.id.activity_formulaire_question_message);

         // Remplissage des champs textes
         tvTitle.setText(title);
         tvMessage.setText(message);

         rootView.addView(myQuestion);
     }
}
```

And on your fragment:

```
QuestionHelper questionHelper = new QuestionHelper(this);
questionHelper.addQuestion(rootView, "Question 1 Title", "1");
questionHelper.addQuestion(rootView, "Question 2 Title", "2");
questionHelper.addQuestion(rootView, "Question 3 Title", "3");
questionHelper.addQuestion(rootView, "Question 4 Title", "4");
```

Comment: May I ask you to have a look at the next step of the project ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516804/android-inflate-view-multiple-time-depending-on-button-state-optimisation You seems to know the subject !